# How to make an svg HTML animation continuously repeat?

Tags: html, animation, svg

```
  <animate  id="one" attributeName="y" from="-21.713" to="10"  begin="0s" dur="2s"  fill="freeze"  /> 
  <animate attributeName="y" from="10" to="-21.713"  begin="one.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

This makes the svg go up once, down once and then it stops. I want it to continuously go up and down.

if I do:

```
repeatCount="indefinite"
```

It will only do one animation and stop.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Animations still don't have consistent behavior between different browsers. You can try adding `repeatCount='0'` as @Adam Moseley suggested below which should work in Firefox. You'll also need to add an `id` to the second `<animate>` so you can use `begin="0s; two.end"` in the first `<animate>` so that it starts again after the second one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this to work you will need to use

repeatCount='0'

Answer (score 0):

```
  <animate  id="one" attributeName="y" from="-21.713" to="10"  begin="0s; two.end" dur="2s"  fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />

  <animate id="two" attributeName="y" from="10" to="-21.713"  begin="one.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

then each animation will start when the other stops. use the ; to give animation one two start points